# Plotting the expression in 2D

Tags: plotting

I'm plotting this function.

Plot[rs + s, {r == 2},  {s, 2, 5}]

When I substitute the value of "r" in the expression then its plot graph, but for unknown "r" in expression and further declaration the value of "r", its unable to draw.

Is there any alternate method to plot the expressions with given fixed values of some variable and with given range of some other variable.

Thanking you.

Comment: You need to look at the documentation a bit further.  `Plot[r s + s /. {r->2}, {s,2,5}]` is what you need, I think.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using manipulate.

```
plot1 = Manipulate[Plot[r s + s, {s, 2, 5}], {r, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much sir.